# Cual es la forma correcta de emplear un sprite sheet con PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

Hoy se me presento un dilema bastante interesante, basicamente queria animar un objeto y no me decidia si cargar todos las superficies en una lista, o guardar en la lista las rutas de las imagenes y acceder a estas cuando las necesitara, es decir ...

```
lista_de_imagenes = []
for i in range(1,10):
    lista_de_imagenes.append(pygame.image.load(ruta_de_imagenes + str(i) + '.png'))
```

vs ....

```
lista_de_imagenes = []
for i in range(1,10):
    lista_de_imagenes.append(ruta_de_imagenes + str(i) + '.png')
def get_image(path):
    return pygame.image.load(path)
```

La pregunta seria entonces: *que es mas eficiente?*

Comment: Soy mayormente autodidacta, por lo que la eficiencia no es mi fuerte. Sin embargo, intentaré responderte. A que te refieres con "mas eficiente"? Más rápido? Que ocupa menos memoria? Otra cosa?

Comment: @DanteS. principalmente que exija menos operaciones a la cpu (para evitar que el juego se relentice), teniendo en cuenta que las llamadas al disco duro  tardan mucho mas que a RAM. Tengo dos opciones, consumir mas RAM y evtiar mas llamadas al disco, con lo cual el juego seria mas rapido en teoria, o hacer mas llamadas al disco y ocupar menos RAM, el juego seguramente sea mas lento. Ya me decidi por la primera, gracias de todas formas